# Trying to use functions from different scripts requires static update, but breaks the code unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I have a number of functions on different scripts that I am trying to using in a win.cs

for example.

```
team.cs

PlayGame();
```

.

```
score.cs

UpdateScore();
```

I have some of the variable set to static, but not all of them, because it isn't needed (yet?)

I tried to put PlayGame(); and UpdateScore(); on the win.cs.  This requires me to do a:

```
 public static void UpdateScore(){}
```

now that this is static I have to go and make all the other vairables associated with the UpdateScore static and then the code breaks.

Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

I have tried using team.PlayGame() as the variable, but that requires the whole static thing too.

Sorry this is kind of hard to explain.

Note:All of the functions are public.

Comment: Create `team T;` `score S;` and in start function initialize `S = gameobject.GetComponent<score>();` `T = gameobject.GetComponent<team>();` in win.c and access through T and S like `T.xxxx();`  `S.xxxxxx();` Lot of option to do this Check Over all links [Here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1SAVC_enIN529IN529&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=accessing%20functions%20in%20other%20scripts%20unity3d)

Comment: ok i will try this thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if Win.cs needs to call UpdateScore on Score.cs then you go as such:

```
public class Win : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField]private Score score = null;

    private void Start(){
        if(this.score == null){
            this.score = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Score>();
        }
    }

    // Then you can use this.score.UpdateScore when needed
}
```

It is possible to do the same action the other way around using event.

```
public class Win:MonoBehaviour{
    public EventHandler<System.EventArg> RaiseUpdateScore;
    protected void OnUpdateScore(EventArg args){
        if(RaiseUpdateScore != null){
           RaiseUpdateScore(this, args);
        }
    }

    public void SomeAction(){
       if(someCondition){
            OnUpdateScore(null);
       }
    }
    void OnDestroy(){ RaiseUpdateScore = null; }
}
```

then on Score.cs

```
public class Score:MonoBehaviour{
    private Win win = null;
    private void Start(){
       this.win = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Win>();
       this.win.RaiseUpdateScore += HandleUpdateScore; 
    }
    private void HandleUpdateScore(object sender , System.EventArg args){}
    private void OnDestroy(){ 
       if(this.win != null){ 
         this.win.RaiseUpdateScore -= HandleUpdateScore;
       } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Component.SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html) to call a method of a script from another script.

Someting like this from `win.cs` script:

```
team teamScript = GameObject.Find("Object that team script is on that").GetComponent<team>();
teamScript.SendMessage("PlayGame", you parameter);
```